# No me inserta datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

Quiero hacer un `insert` con MySQL a la base de datos, pero no lo hace correctamente, cuando lo hago no me muestra ningún mensaje ni nada, solo cuando actualizo la página es que muestra los datos, los inserta todos menos uno que es el último.

Dejos pantallas y código, tal vez me entienden:

[image: imagen 1]

Ingreso de datos:

[image: Ingreso de datos]

Después de ingresar datos:

[image: despues de ingresar datos]

Después de actualizar la página

[image: Despues de actualizar]

```
//insert de los datos
<?php
//conexion a la base de datos
include 'conexion.php';


//almacena los datos ingresados en los textboxs
$nomb=$_POST['Nombres']; 
$apell=$_POST['Apellidos'];
$ident=$_POST['Identidad'];
$email=$_POST['Correo']; 
$user=$_POST['Usuario']; 
$pass=$_POST['Password'];
$perm=$_POST['Nivel_Permiso'];

//Sentencia insert que afectara la tabla usuarios 
$sql="INSERT INTO usuario (Nombres, Apellidos, Identidad, correo, Usuario, Password, Nivel_Permiso) VALUES
('$nomb', '$apell', '$ident', '$email','$user', '$pass', '$perm')";

echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);



?>



//funcion javascript y ajax para validar y hacer la llamada del insert
function agregarusuarios(Nombres,Apellidos,Identidad,Correo,Usuario,Password,Nivel_Permiso) {

    cadena="&Nombres=" + Nombres + 
           "&Apellidos=" + Apellidos +  
            "&Identidad=" + Identidad +
            "&Correo=" + Correo +
            "&Usuario=" + Usuario +
            "&Password=" + Password +
            "&Nivel_Permiso" + Nivel_Permiso;

    //validacion de ingreso de datos con ajax e y llamada     del insert
    $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"agregardatos.php",
     data:cadena,
     success:function (r) {
         if (r==1) {
             //al momento que se agregue un dato se vuela a recargar la tabla

             alertify.success("Usuario Registrado Correctamente"); 
             $('#tabla').load('tabla.php');
         }else{
            alertify.success("Fallo en el servidor");


         }
     }

    });

}



 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Usuarios</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertifyjs/css/alertify.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertifyjs/css/themes/default.css">

        <script src="librerias/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--llamado de las funciones que estan en el archivo funciones.js-->
        <script src="funciones.js"></script>
        <script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="librerias/alertifyjs/alertify.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!--Uso de la tablaTabla-->
    <div class="container">
    <div id="tabla"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal para registro de usuarios nuevos -->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalRegistro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agrega Usuarios </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- campos para registrar usuarios -->
          <label>Nombres: </label>
            <input type="text" id="Nombres" class="form-control input-sm" name="Nombres"><br>

            <label>Apellidos: </label>
            <input type="text" id="Apellidos" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Apellidos" ><br>

            <label>Identidad: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Identidad" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Identidad" ><br>

              <label>Correo: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Correo" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Correo" ><br>

              <label>Usuario: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Usuario" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Usuario" ><br>

              <label>Password: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Password" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Password" ><br>

              <label>Nivel de Permiso: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Nivel_Permiso" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Nivel_Permiso" ><br>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="guardarnuevo">
            Agregar
            </button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal para edicion de nuevos usuarios-->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdicion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Actualizar Datos</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <label>Nombres: </label>
            <input type="text" id="Nombrese" class="form-control input-sm" name="Nombrese"><br>

            <label>Apellidos: </label>
            <input type="text" id="Apellidose" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Apellidose" ><br>

            <label>Identidad: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Identidade" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Identidade" ><br>

              <label>Correo: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Correoe" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Correoe" ><br>

              <label>Usuario: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Usuarioe" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Usuarioe" ><br>

              <label>Password: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Passworde" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Passworde" ><br>

              <label>Nivel de Permiso: </label>
              <input type="text" id="Nivel_Permisoe" class="form-control input-sm"  name="Nivel_Permisoe" ><br>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="actualizadatos" data-dismiss="modal">Actualizar</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>


//codigo javascript llamar la tabla y el evento del boton guardar
<!--llamada a la tabla.php-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla').load('tabla.php');
});
</script>
<!--llamada a la funcion inserta usuarios-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#guardarnuevo').click(function(){
        Nombres=$('#Nombres').val();
        Apellidos=$('#Apellidos').val();
        Identidad=$('#Identidad').val();
        Correo=$('#Correo').val();
        Usuario=$('#Usuario').val();
        Password=$('#Password').val();
        Nivel_Permiso=$('#Nivel_Permiso').val();
    agregarusuarios(Nombres,Apellidos,Identidad,Correo,Usuario,Password,Nivel_Permiso)
    });
});
</script>
```

Gracias por sus respuestas :)

Comment: Tu query es muy vulnerable a inyección sql, usa sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Deberías probar a meter el código de la llamada a la BD en un try{}catch{} de ese modo podrás ver algún error y saber que está pasando.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error se te produce a la hora de realizar la `query`. Intenta lo siguiente:

```js
$sql="INSERT INTO usuario (Nombres, Apellidos, Identidad, correo, Usuario, Password, Nivel_Permiso) VALUES($nomb, $apell, $ident, $email,$user, $pass, $perm)";

if (mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) === TRUE) {
    //en tu llamada de AJAX verificas si es 1 la repsuesta?¿
    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: Gracias ya resolvi el problema :)